# NullPointerException when trying to set a double array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors, nullpointerexception

This is the relevant code I think

```
class Sudoku {
    int[][] grid;     

    void generateSudokuFromInput()
    {

      grid = new int[][]   <--- java.lang.NullPointerException at Sudoku.generateSudokuFromInput(Sudoku.java:309)
      {
         (...)
      }
    }

    void solveIt() {

      generateSudokuFromInput(); 

    }

}
```

Keep getting NullPointer error

Comment: Can you post the exact code with a few edits as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to declaring the array size later (as described in other answers), you can also just initialize your array when declaring it:

```
class Sudoku {
    int[][] grid = {
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    };

    void generateSudokuFromInput() {
        // just set the values on grid, e.g. grid[0][0] = 9
    }

    void solveIt() {
        generateSudokuFromInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: Same initialization code will also work inside generateSudokuFromInput() method.

Comment: Er, yeah. Bit of a brain lapse there. I'll update my example :P

Answer (score 3):

When declaring multidimensional array, you must specify all the dimensions except the last one.

E.g

```
grid = new int [3][];
```

This will work nicely.

Comment: Don't have to, if you initializing it.

Answer (score 1):

To create an array you must have to specify the subscript value.

```
grid = new int[2][];
grid[0]=new int[2];
grid[1]=new int[5];
```

or

```
grid=new int[3][3];
```

To learn more about arrays refer [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) document.

Comment: No, you don't have to do that. There is another option.

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov I've mentioned possible ways and I'm not sure what he/she wants.

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov - I'm not sure these answers are worthy of a downvote; they **are** good options if the OP *doesn't* want to initialize the array on assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide size for the first dimension:

```
grid = new int[3][];
```

Else, how do you expect the second dimension to work?
A 2-dimensions array [i][j] basically means "My array has i arrays, each of them have j values". If there's no i, it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Not necessarily. This works just as well: grid = new int[][] {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};

Comment: Yes, because it explicitly initialises the array, which has the same effect.